# Doctrine 2 onDelete CASCADE set to deleted

Tags: php, doctrine, cascade

I'm working on a project where I never actually delete any records. I am trying to get Doctrine to set an entity to "deleted" (flag) on cascade. Here are two entities to illustrate the associations I have currently;

**Model_Account**

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Model_Profile",mappedBy="Account")
 */
protected $Profiles;
```

**Model_Profile**

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model_Account",inversedBy="Profiles")
 * @JoinColumn(name="AccountId",referencedColumnName="Id",onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $Account;
```

When I delete an account, I wish all profiles associated with said account to be removed also, but only by having their "Deleted" flag set to true. I have no idea where to go from here. Do I need to tap into an event to override the default delete and just set my flag?

Thank you.

Comment: Some googling for doctrine 2 soft delete should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up Doctrine2 soft delete (there's an extension for it) and then use Doctrine's cascade operations instead of those at the RDBMS level by setting `cascade={"remove"}` on the entity.